# How to read Json Android

Tags: java, android

i so confused ! i'm so trying to read this json but i can't :-(
here is my code :

{"status":"loged_in","token":"8e88776a14f4da4ef8e00955f83e1397","nikeName":"سعید"}

```
        try {
            postTextandGetRespons("http://gfac.ir/KatibehPayam/Service/login.php");

            JSONArray messages = new JSONArray(responseString);

            for ( int i=0; i<= messages.length();i++){

                JSONObject c = messages.getJSONObject(i);

                Status[0] = c.getString("status");
                Status[1] = c.getString("token");
                Status[2] = c.getString("nikeName");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: please learn basics first ... `{..}` is not a JSON array

Comment: You should show your response string and error log.

Comment: Where did responseString comfrom?

Comment: Selvin thank's for your tip, sure i do that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `responseString` contains an object not an array so use `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray`

```
JSONObject message = new JSONObject(responseString);
String status = message.getString("status");
String token = message.getString("token");
String nikeName = message.getString("nikeName");
```